# lightning:spinner solution that finally works (using custom events, not aura:waiting)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events, aura-handler

Lightning components without a working loading indicator are just not professional.

Too bad that there is not code example out there that seems to work under real-world circumstances.Every blog out there is recommending to use the too generic aura events

```
<aura:handler event="aura:waiting" action="{!c.showWaiting}"/>
<aura:handler event="aura:doneWaiting" action="{!c.hideWaiting}"/>
```

and the [Lightning experts have to explain](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155175) over and over why this is not a stable solution.

So what I am asking for is a spinner solution that

1. Uses custom component events for showing/hiding the spinner
2. Uses `lightning:spinner` and not Design system `div` nightmares
3. Works in hierarchies of components. Child components can ask for a spinner.
4. Needs minimal code. So no 10 lines of CSS in every situation that needs it.

Sharing is caring ;-) I will open a bounty to say thanks for a great solution.

Comment: I'm putting this as a comment as I'm not sure this is exactly what you want. https://github.com/rapsacnz/LightFrame - hierarchies - yes, events - no ( you get by reference and call a method ) - minimal - yes. Not sure about your point 2

Comment: So I now use a component called Base that I extend. It handles spinners, notifications and server calls (so far). Works great.

Comment: @CasparHarmer This works for a single component, but not for hierarchies, right? I need a solution with events that bubble in the component tree.

Comment: @RobertSösemann Can you add more details how the spinner component would/you like it to  behave inside hierarchy of components. A small usecase will help us understand what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of writing many lines of code, you can achieve with below code.

Component code

```
 <aura:attribute name="IsSpinner" type="Boolean"/>
      <aura:if isTrue="{!v.IsSpinner}">
       <lightning:spinner variant="brand"  size="large" />
      </aura:if>
```

Helper Js Code

```
showSpinner:function(cmp){

  cmp.set("v.IsSpinner",true);

},

 hideSpinner:function(cmp){

  cmp.set("v.IsSpinner",false);

}
```

Call above methods to show & hide spinner.

Comment: This wouldn't work for hierarchies of components and I doubt that changing an attribute which always rerender the <aura:if> part

Comment: if you pass the attributes to the component hierarchy, it should work just fine